# Reload MySQL data inside a DIV using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I need to make a moderate system like the one in fmylife.com. Basically the problem I have is loading the MySQL query using Ajax (without page refreshing) in to a div.
MySQL query

```
$sql = mysql_query(“SELECT * FROM posts WHERE active =’0’” LIMIT 1) or die (mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

HTML

```
<div class=”post-body”><?php echo $row[‘sitepost’];?></div>
```

this data should be reloaded when pressing "yes" or "no" buttons. thanks in advance.

Comment: @ Sarfraz - thats what i like to know. the Ajax code. @ T-Shirt Dude yes im trying from so many days now. at last i came here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@mgraph is close but if you want to do this on a button click

in **post.php**:

```
//$UserOption will be Yes/No for button clicks or empty string for first load of the page

$UserOption = $_REQUEST['UserClicked'];

//Id will be set if a vote has been clicked or empty string if it's the first load
$Id = $_REQUEST['Id'];

//(Do something with $UserOption)

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE active ='0' LIMIT 1") or die (mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo $row['sitepost'];
```

**JS**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   update(null,null);
})

function update(Id, Vote) {
    $(".post-body").eq(0).load("post.php?UserClicked=" + Vote + "&Id=" + Id);
}
</script>
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="post-body"></div>


<button type="button" onclick="update(1, 'Yes');">Yes</button>
<button type="button" onclick="update(1, 'No');">No</button>



<button type="button" onclick="update(2, 'Yes');">Yes</button>
<button type="button" onclick="update(2, 'No');">No</button>
```

**Alternate HTML/JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#yes").click(function(){
        update('Yes');
    })
    $("#no").click(function(){
        update('No');
    })
    update();
})

function update(Vote) {
    $(".post-body").eq(0).load("post.php?UserClicked=" + Vote);
}
</script>

<div class="post-body"></div>
<button id="yes" type="button">Yes</button>
<button id="no" type="button">No</button>
```

Comment: this is great but where is the click event?

Comment: Actually, I've just hard-coded it onto the buttons in the html... You could always give the buttons/divs an Id and attach a click using jQuery. See my revisions for an alternate way of attaching the click

Comment: @ Basic thats really nice. thank you. one more thing i like to ask can post a id alone with the vote. other wise mysql query will out put the same result isn't it?

Comment: Sure - presumably you've got multiple buttons for yes/no - so I'd suggest you go back to the function-on-button method I first proposed. I'll edit it as appropriate

Comment: Note that if the buttons are actually going to be generated server-side on each page refresh you'd actually need to return the HTML for them, including the Id in the post body. Also, don't forget to implement a mechanism to prevent a user clicking twice - eg disabling the button when clicked or similar (but that's beyond the scope of this Q). Also, look into using `mysqli_` functions instead of `mysql_` they're better maintained and allow "Parameterised Queries" which are important to prevent [SQL Injection attacks](https://threatpost.com/en_us/blogs/anatomy-sql-injection-attack-022510)

Answer (score 5):

in **post.php**:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE active ='0' LIMIT 1") or die (mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo $row['sitepost'];
```

**JS**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#yes").click(function(){
      $(".post-body").eq(0).load("post.php");
   })
})
</script>
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="yes">YES</div>
<div class="post-body"></div>
```

Comment: thanks how can i make it to work when a button click (click event)? say button id is "yes"

Answer (score 4):

You can add `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);` . Thereby, when you clicked YES button, scroll move up to top. It looks nice.