# how to insert SQL values without reload?( jquery + PHP)

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have a form where I keep various fields (name, email, comments) in a mysql database, the data is written, but I would like to show data without reloading the page, press the submit button and view the new comment. .

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="noticia_id" value="<?php echo $id;  ?>"><br>
        <p><label>NOMBRE *</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="usuario"></p>
        <p><label for="email">EMAIL (No se publicará) *</label>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email"></p>
        <p><label for="comment">COMENTARIO</label>
        <textarea name="comentario" id="comment" cols="100%" rows="10" tabindex="4"></textarea></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Enviar " /></p>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
    //conectamos a la base  
    $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
    //Seleccionamos la base  
    mysql_select_db("mostra",$connect);
    $id=$_POST['noticia_id'];
    $nick=$_POST['usuario']; 
    $email=$_POST['email']; 
    $comentario=$_POST['comentario']; 
    $query = "INSERT INTO comentarios (usuario,email,comentario,noticia_id, fecha) VALUES('$nick','$email','$comentario','$id', NOW())";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $query = "UPDATE  noticias SET num_comentarios= num_comentarios+1 where id_noticia='".$id."'";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}

?>
```

How do I create a jquery function or an other method to insert this data without having to reload the page?

I've looked at tutorials but I can not help me!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You also need to protect against SQL injection. I'd recommend parameterized queries.

Comment: Concerning what BAF said, take a look at PDO as well.

Comment: @jonathan de M Yes, I've gotten into this page, but do not understand how to do it with my parameters: (, I'm newbie: S, I tried but I can not with my parameters

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code contains an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Please [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli) so you can use [prepared statements with parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: Like I said, I am a rookie, I do not understand why the SQL injected, what is? Moment I'd settle on running this code without reloading the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript use Jquery to make a AJAX call as such:

Say you have a php page called url.php which is doing the SQL insertions and that you are passing a parameter called par1 do the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ver.php?par1=" + parValue,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(result) {
        // use the result as you wish in your html here
}});
```

then in ver.php do:

```
$par1 = $_POST['par1'];
```

Ok try this code:

HTML code:

```
<fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="noticia_id" value="<?php echo $id;  ?>"><br>
    <p><label>NOMBRE *</label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre" name="usuario"></p>
    <p><label for="email">EMAIL (No se publicará) *</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"></p>
    <p><label for="comment">COMENTARIO</label>
    <textarea name="comentario" id="comment" cols="100%" rows="10" tabindex="4"></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="send_data()" tabindex="5" value="Enviar " /></p>

</fieldset>

Javascript Code:

function send_data()
{
    var usuario = $('#nombre').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var commentario = $('#comment').val();

    $.ajax({
    url: "ver.php?usuario=" + usuario + "&email=" + email + "&comentario=" + commentario,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(result) {
        // use the result as you wish in your html here
    }});

}

PHP Code:

$connect=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
//Seleccionamos la base  
mysql_select_db("mostra",$connect);
$nick=$_POST['usuario']; 
$email=$_POST['email']; 
$comentario=$_POST['comentario']; 
$query = "INSERT INTO comentarios (usuario,email,comentario,noticia_id, fecha) VALUES('$nick','$email','$comentario','$id', NOW())";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$query = "UPDATE  noticias SET num_comentarios= num_comentarios+1 where id_noticia='".$id."'";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: you're using GET in ajax and post in php

Comment: What would $ par1 = $ _POST ['par1'];? i don't understand :S. 've pasted inside <head> script and does not work :S

Comment: That is php code, $par1 will hold the value that is being passed to ver.php in the par1 parameter which you can use to insert the value into your database.

Comment: forgive my clumsiness, but $ par1 = $ _POST ['par1']; contain contain the same value as $ id = $ _POST ['article_id'];, no?

$ id = $ _POST ['article_id']; indicates the page number on which we are now

Comment: that is just a generic parameter to show you how the AJAX code works. Add whatever parameters and values you want/need into the AJAX url.

Comment: thanks, okay, but still, with my parameters, as I've said, I do not get it to work. I do not know how it works. No I do with my parameters

Comment: Thanks!! but..the editor gives me error in the javascript , exactly in "   // use the result as you wish in your html here
    });
"

Comment: The values ​​are stored in the database, but not shown on the page when you send it, I have to refresh the page to display the value

Comment: if within the javascript put a alert (user), when I give send the javascript alert function tells me "undefined"

Comment: Thats because you are not actually sending anything back from the php. You need to echo the values from the php page that you want loaded onto the screen. Once you have done this, result will contain these values and using jquery you can load these values into the page without reloading the page

Comment: you mean I have to print into the php code $ _POST ['user'], $ _POST ['email'];?

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is the best way to accomplish what you are looking for also your code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection I suggest doing your homework on PDO prepared statements to help safeguard against it. Take a look here [Reload MySQL data inside a DIV using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070607/reload-mysql-data-inside-a-div-using-ajax)

Comment: Sorry, but I think I did not put any negative feedback

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('form').submit(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                data:{'usuario':$(this).find("input[name=usuario]").val(),'email':$(this).find("input[name=email]").val()},
                success:function(returnData){
                    console.log(returnData)
                }
            })
            return false;
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: -1, code dumps are not answers.  You have not explained what this code is, how it works, why it was written, or how it will help fix the problem.

Comment: Hello :) Thank you, I just test your code, but not working. I've pasted inside  <head> script and does not work: (