# JavaScript reload while mysql results

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

**Problem:**
Tried reloading results from MySQL in index.php, using JavaScript.
But for some reason it didn't work, I followed a stackoverflow answer.

When clicking the ID 'yes', nothing happens.
I have defnied the jQuery liberally, and getting 0 errors in console.

**Question**

What have I done wrong? How do I fix it?

Basically I want the JavaScript to reload / refresh results from mySQL, if there are new ones when you click the ID 'yes'.

```
                echo '<div id="messages">';
                while($row = $fetch->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )) {
                        echo 
                        '<div class="background">'.$row['email'].' <span style="margin-left: 10px;"><font color="#ff0000">UNANSWERED</font></span><span id="right"><a href="index.php?recover='.$row['recover_id'].'">Read More</a></span></div><br />
                        ';
                }
                echo '</div>';
```

The HTML

```
<span id="yes">RELOAD</span>
```

The JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#yes").click(function(){
        $("#message").eq(0).load("index.php");
    })
})
</script>
```

Followed this: [Reload MySQL data inside a DIV using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070607/reload-mysql-data-inside-a-div-using-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your div in the first code block is #messages

Your JS in the second code block looks for #message

Need to line those up