# How to reload MySQL records in AJAX div while results are being returned?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I want to know how to reload a `<div>` using `AJAX` where the content being displayed are records retrieved from the `MySQL` `database`. The tricky part is that I want the `<div>` to display each result for 30 seconds and then reload to display the next result.

Here is the `media table`:

```
_______________________________________________
| FIELD 1 |  FIELD 2  |  FIELD 3  |  FIELD 4  |
-----------------------------------------------
|   ID    |   TVOne   |   TVTwo   |  Active   |
-----------------------------------------------
|   15    |   no      |     no    |    no     |
-----------------------------------------------
|   29    |   yes     |     no    |   yes     |
-----------------------------------------------
|   53    |    no     |     no    |    no     |
-----------------------------------------------
|   71    |   yes     |    yes    |    yes    |
-----------------------------------------------
```

In the `<div>` located on TVOne's page I want it to load record 29 and 71. In the `<div>` located on TVTwo's page I want it to only load record 71. This `table` is modified by the user on the back-end, so the results are always going to be different.

I was reading [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070607/reload-mysql-data-inside-a-div-using-ajax) and I believe the `javascript` selector `.eq()` could be a piece of the puzzle, but I'm not sure how to put it all together.

The page where the `<div>` is located is called `index4.php`. The previous page (`index3.php`) performs a query to see if any of the records are set to active, if they are then it sets `num_rows` to `$count` and goes to `index4.php?count=$count`, if not it goes back to the beginning of the display sequence `index.php`.

Here is `index3.php` redirect function:

```
<?php
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM media WHERE Active = 1 AND TVTwo = 1");
$count = $result->num_rows;
if($count > 0){$media = "index4.php?count=$count";}
else{$media = "index.php";}
?>

<script>
refresh=window.setTimeout(function(){location.href="<?php echo $media;?>"},15000);
</script>
```

Here is my `AJAX` code to load the `<div>`:

```
<script>
function MediaQuery(qty)
    {
    if (qty=="")
        {
        document.getElementById("Media").innerHTML="";
        return;
        }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("Media").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","../process/QueryMedia.php?count="+qty,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

Here is QueryMedia.php:

```
<?php
$count = $_GET["count"];

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM media WHERE Active = 1 AND TVTwo = 1 LIMIT $count");

if(!$result_sql = $mysqli->query($sql))
    {
    echo QueryCheck("getting the media records ","from the media",$mysqli);
    }

// fetch it here
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code or we have to assume you want us to do your work for you, which we won't do. You basically found all you need already: A server-side script to provide the data, an AJAX call, a JS thingy to replace the view and a JS timeout to trigger the automatic reloading.

Comment: @TillHelge I don't really have much other than the basic `AJAX` call to load the `<div>`, but I can appreciate what you're saying, so I will post it.

Comment: @TillHelge That's exactly how I feel, like I've got all the ingredients...I just don't have the recipe.

Comment: Somehow you left out the really interesting part. What format did you choose to transfer the data? JSON? And what exactly is the problem with the code you have? Where are you stuck? What doesn't work?

Comment: @TillHelge I literally posted all of my code, so if you don't see it, I don't have it. Transferring the data is done using `PHP`, unless I'm not understanding what you're asking? The problem I have with the code I have is...well...it doesn't exist yet. All I've got is a single AJAX call to load the `<div>`, nothing else. That's where I'm stuck, I don't know how to get to the next step or what direction to go in.

Comment: Well...I don't know where to begin, to be honest. Maybe we should move this to the chat to avoid cluttering up the comments and to get to the solution faster.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28810/discussion-between-till-helge-and-andrew-fox)

Comment: @TillHelge Sorry, I didn't see your reply until now, it was the end of the work day. I've got it solved now though, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I got this figured out.

1. `index3.php` checks the database to see if anything has been set to "active" (and in this case it also checks to see what display it's been set to display on).
2. When it finds a record, it sends the variable `$i` (used as a key and set to the highest result) via `$_GET` to `index4.php`.
3. When the `index4.php` page loads, it triggers `function MediaQuery(i)` which then asks `QueryMedia.php` for the database record based on the key given.
4. Once the `QueryMedia.php` results are loaded, the `i` key is reduced by 1 and then the `function MediaQuery(i)` is sent again after a short delay.
5. Once the `i` key gets to the last result, which is always going to be `0`, the page redirects to the start of the display sequence on `index.php`.

Here is `index3.php`:

```
<?php
$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM media WHERE Media_Active = 1 AND Media_TVTwo = 1");
$count = $sql->num_rows;

if($count != 0)// If there are results returned then redirect to the media page.
    {
    $i = $count - 1;

    $media = "index4.php?i=$i";
    }
else // Else redirect to the first page.
    {
    $media = "index.php";
    }
?>

<script>
window.setTimeout(function(){location.href="<?php echo $media;?>"},20000);
</script>
```

Here is `index4.php`:

```
<script>
function MediaQuery(i)
    {
    if (i < 0)
        {
        window.setTimeout(function(){location.href="index.php"},0);
        return;
        }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("Media").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            var i = document.getElementById("i").innerHTML;
            var i = i-1;
            setTimeout(function() {MediaQuery(i)},20000);
            }
        }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","../process/QueryMedia.php?i="+i,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>

<body onload="MediaQuery(<?php echo $_GET['i'];?>)">
```

Here is `QueryMedia.php`:

```
<?php
$i = $_GET["i"];

    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM media WHERE Media_Active = 1 AND Media_TVTwo = 1 ORDER BY Media_Name");

    if(!$result_sql = $mysqli->query($sql))
        {
        echo QueryCheck("getting the media records ","from the media",$mysqli);
        }

    $id = array();
    while($idquery = $result_sql->fetch_assoc())
        {
        $id[] = $idquery['Media_ID'];
        }

    $sql2 = ("SELECT * FROM media WHERE Media_ID = $id[$i]");

    if(!$result_sql2 = $mysqli->query($sql2))
        {
        echo QueryCheck("getting the media records ","from the media",$mysqli);
        }

    while($media = $result_sql2->fetch_assoc())
        {
        $img = $media['Media_Name'];
        $width = $media['Media_Width'];
        $height = $media['Media_Height'];
        $msg = $media['Media_Msg'];
        }
?>

<img src="../images/media/<?php echo $img; ?>" border="2" width="<?php echo $width; ?>px" height="<?php echo $height; ?>px">

<p align="center" class="f24" style="margin:5px"><?php echo $msg; ?></p>
<p id="i" style="display:none;"><?php echo $i; ?></p><!-- used to return the key value -->
```

I have no doubt this may not be the most efficient way to do things, there are a lot of server requests going on and I'm sure the code is a little bloated. If anyone wants to help me make it better, I would definitely appreciate the input.